# how to clear ie status bar text when page loading,or the URL of the link the mouse is on?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I hooks the ie and wanna clear the text when page loading, or the URL of the link the mouse is on，i change the parameter with the function

```
Invoke(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags,
DISPPARAMS* pDispParams, VARIANT* pvarResult,
EXCEPINFO* pExcepInfo, UINT* puArgErr)
pDispParams->rgvarg[0].bstrVal = L"";
```

but it's not work,can anybody tell me how to solve it? thx

[image]

Comment: _"but it's not work"_ Not only that's not correct grammar, it's to vague for asking here. What exactly _doesn't work_? Compiler errors, runtime errors?

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. Please also note that the details you supply, namely the details of the signature of `IDispatch::Invoke`, are completely irrelevant. Hint: It looks like you can use scripting for a Windows "HTML application" (filename extension .hta) to achieve what you want, keeping in mind that the .hta specific HTML elements don't work anymore as of Windows 8 and later.